# Can one make a siyum mesechta if it was learned in English translation?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, talmud-gemara, translation, siyum

If someone has some trouble with Aramaic and learned parts of a mesechta in English translation (for example with an Artscroll Gemara), can he still make a siyum?

Comment: I can't imagine why not. Aramaic is not Lashon HaKodesh, and learning gemara is about understanding it, not _saying_ it.

Comment: Shraga, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for bringing your question here. Please consider registering your account to gain access to all the features of this site. I look forward to seeing you around! (And if I may, I find @HodofHod's second point above to be particularly salient.)

Comment: It is called torah *sheh baal peh*.

Comment: @HodofHod Saying it is an important part ([Avos ch. 1, Boaz note 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37946&st=&pgnum=311&hilite=)). If I remember correctly, Bruriah punched someone for learning not out loud.

Comment: ba, that may be true in a general sense, but would it have an effect on ones ability to make a siyum? I.e. lets say someone learned parts of the mesechta without saying the words?

Comment: @HodofHod, perhaps not, but it has some aspects that make it more special than English, eg.

Comment: there are opinions which include Aramaic with lashon hakodesh. the important thing learning torah sh'baal peh is understanding what you learned. Otherwise it isn't learning at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not a Rav so please confirm the following with your local orthodox rabbi.

The [following](http://www.kof-k.org/articles/040208030401W-36%20Making%20a%20Siyum.pdf) is from Kof-K.

Horav Chaim Pinchus Sheinberg Shlita
is of the opinion that a person who went through the mesechta with an English
translation may make a siyum. However, the person who is using the English has to be
actually working on understanding the Gemorah and not just reading the words like a
book. For a person who needs the English, working through the entire Gemorah in
English, is a very big simcha.18

Sources: 18
Horav Yisroel Belsky Shlita agreed to this. If one said he would finish a certain mesechta and it is coming close to the time he said he was going to finish, he may read the words without going into the meaning so deeply (Shraga Hameir 8:5). Refer to Yoma Tova L’rabanan 8:5:footnotes 9-20 if one may make a siyum if he finished the mesechta by listening to Torah tapes or a shiur. Refer to Vayivorech Dovid 2:177