# When is learning "done"?

Tags: torah-study, time, siyum

I learn with a group of people each week and we take turns leading. I need a lot of time to prepare and usually start a week in advance. I read and review multiple times during the week. If I am tasked with leading the group in a week when I will complete the masechta, do I make the hadran when I finish my first run through or at any other time (such as a few runs later when I feel I [understand](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31817/what-level-of-understanding-is-required-in-learning-for-purposes-of-making-a-s) the content) or do I wait until I "finish" with the group even though this might be the 5th time I am going through the same section?

This becomes an issue if I am going to lead on a date which is within the 9 days and then host a siyum. If my prep has me complete the masechta before the 9 days begin but the group convenes during the nine days have I "finished" during the nine days or before them?

Comment: Aren't you expecting to learn more by interacting with your group? So your learning isn't "done" until after you've heard your group's ideas.

Comment: That isn't always how it goes. The leader teaches right through because he knows it already, indicating that he has already "learned" it. If we waited until there was nothing new to learn, we would never have a siyum.

Comment: Wouldn't the group make the siyum when the group is done?

Comment: But I'm done days before the group. And it isn't like the group, en masse, recites the hadran together (at least that hasn't been the case). Could it be that I recite the hadran when I finish learning it and then someone ELSE in the group says it when we finish it together?