# Studying the Written Torah in English

Tags: halacha, hebrew, torah-study, mitzvah, language

In terms of fulfilling the Mitzvah of Talmud Torah, when studying the Written Torah, must one learn the translation in tandem with the Hebrew words? Or is it sufficient to understand the meaning, messages and translation of the Written Torah without reading the Hebrew that it's written in?

Comment: [not an answer] I recall seeing elsewhere on this site that it is permissible to learn written Torah without understanding it. Presumably, since there are the targumim, one may learn it in one's own language.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18446/759

Comment: why wouldnt it be talmud torah?

Comment: @ray Because Moshe wrote it in Hebrew and many laws are derived ipso facto. Additionally, the Torah is required to be written in Hebrew - Lashon Kodesh - so the fact that it's written in Hebrew is obviously very important to the Written Torah. It's not hard to see why it would be required to be studied with the Hebrew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rambam writes fairly emphatically in a [responsum](http://www.sefaria.org/Iggerot_HaRambam.7.5?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) that Torah study depends not upon the Hebrew language, but upon the intent of the words:

> ואין הפרש שהבין אותו הענין מלשון קודש או מלשון ערבי או מלשון ארמי הכונה היא הבנת ענינים בכל לשון שיהיה
>
> There is no difference if he understood the matter in L'shon Hakodesh (Hebrew), or in Arabic, or in Aramaic. The point is the understanding of the matters in whatever language they be.

Although the questioner spoke Arabic and was concerned about his being limited to learning Peirush Hamishnayot in Arabic, and Rambam's context might be construed to that; Oral Torah, not Writtesn Torah, his emphatic statement seems to include all Torah study.

---

It seems especially likely that this is meant as a universal statement given that the questioner didn't express embarrassment over the fact that he was learning the Mishna commentary in Arabic, rather than Hebrew. In fact it wasn't even available in Hebrew. Thus it wouldn't make sense for this statement to be about the PH in particular. Rather, it seems to be a universal statement.

As with any text the original often conveys nuances that translations don't carry. (It is for this reason that Rambam writes in the responsum that his Mishne Torah will not be translated to Arabic.) Therefore, everyone would certainly agree that there is value in learning Torah texts (be they Torah, Mishna, Gemara, or anything else) in their original, in that this will further ones appreciation of them. Nevertheless, the implication of the Rambam is that the mitzva is fulfilled with trans. as well.

Answer (score 2):

The Gemara in Berachot 13a says that there is a dispute about whether the Torah was given in Lashon ha-Kodesh or in every language. The Shitah Mekubetzet ibid. cites the Ra'avad who explains that the question is about Torah study: if the Torah was given in every language, one can study it in every language, but if it was not, then one only fulfills והגית בו יומם ולילה in Lashon ha-Kodesh.

ואם תאמר ומאי נפקא לן מינה אי בלשון הקודש נאמרה או בכל לשון, **אי לשינון בכל לשון ששינה וקורא יצא**. ורש"י ז"ל פירש פרק ב' דמגלה דנפקא מינה לענין לקרות בספר תורה בבית הכנסת... אבל הראב"ד ז"ל כתב וזה לשונו: הא דדייקינן מרבנן על התורה אם נאמרה בכל לשון אם לא לא על הכתיבה שכתב משה נאמרה שהכל יודעים שלא נכתבה בספר אלא בלשון הקדש ולא נכתבו שאר לשונות אלא על האבנים שבגלגל כדכתיב באר היטב. אלא על התלמוד שלמדו הקדוש ברוך הוא למשה ומשה למד אותה לישראל לפי שהיו בהם גרים משאר לשונות [נסתפק לנו] אם **היה מלמדה לכל אחד ואחד בלשונו וכן כל אחד ואחד יוצא ידי שינון בלשונו או שמא לכולם שונה בלשון הקדש ואין אדם יוצא ידי והגית בו אלא בלשון הקדש**

R. Meir Soloveitchik (cited in Chiddushei Ha-Griz, Sotah 33a) explains that the Ra'avad does not intend to say that if the Torah was not given in other languages then one doesn't fulfill the mitzvah of Talmud Torah, because obviously one fulfill the mitzvah regardless;  learning in another language is no worse than thinking about learning, with which one fulfills the mitzvah. Rather, the Ra'avad is referring to another aspect of the mitzvah which is fulfilled merely by reading the words. Whether one fulfills this additional aspect in another language depends on whether the Torah was given in other languages:

ודברי הראב"ד צ"ב במש"כ דלרבנן דכה"ת כולה בלשה"ק נאמרה אין אדם יוצא יד"ח והגית בו אלא בלה"ק, והרי זה פשוט דבכל לשון יוצא יד"ח מצות ת"ת, דהא לא גרע מהרהור בד"ת דפשוט דיוצא בו יד"ח מצות ת"ת, וכן כשלומד תורה שבע"פ יוצא בו יד"ח מצות ת"ת. והנראה מבואר בזה דחוץ מקיום מצות ת"ת, נאמר עוד דכשקורא ד"ת, דין ותורת קריאה עלה, ונאמר בה דינים מסויימים, וממילא לרבנן כשקורא בשאר לשונות, אף דאיתקיימא ביה מצות ת"ת, מ"מ לא יצא יד"ח "והגית בו", דהוא דין ותורת קריאה דרק בלשון הקודש יש דין ותורת קריאה עלה, אבל בשאר לשונות לא הוי שם ותורת קריאה עלה...מהג"ר מאיר הלוי סאלאווייציק שליט"א, והסכים עמו בזה אביו מרן הגרי"ז זצ"ל

Tosafot in Berachot 13a says that according to the view that the Torah was given in every language it means that each word of God "divided" into seventy languages: בכל לשון נאמרה בסיני שכל דבור ודבור שהיה יוצא מפי הקב"ה היה מתחלק לשבעים לשון. The Keren Orah in Sotah 33a explains that the ramification of whether the Torah was given in Lashon ha-Kodesh or not according to this view is whether one fulfills the mitzvah of Talmud Torah in other languages:

והיה נראה לומר דלענין מצות ת"ת קאמר דעיקר מצות הלימוד הוא המקרא, ולחד מ"ד אין מברכין אלא על המקרא. כדאיתא בברכות פ"ק (י"א ע"ב). ומספקא לן בהא אי קיים המצוה בכל לשון, או דווקא בלה"ק. אלא דגם בזה אין לספק אלא בכתיבתה היכי היא, דבע"פ אסור ללמוד מקרא. ועדיין צ"ע בזה

See also the Meiri in Berachot who explains the Gemara along these lines as well:

אף כל התורה בכל לשון נאמרה כלומר שאע"פ שבלשון הקודש נאמרה מפי הקב"ה למשה וממשה לישראל וכן שאם נכתבה בלשון אחר אין בו קדושה **מ"מ על מנת כן נאמרה שיהא שנונה או למודה מותר בכל לשון ויוצא בו ידי הגיית יום ולילה** ואע"פ שבמסכת סוטה נאמרו קצת דברים שהם טעונין לשון הקדש כגון מקרא בכורים וכו' מ"מ קריאת התורה דרך כלל אין למדין אותה ממצוה פרטית וכו' ולפי דרכך למדת בפי' הסוגיא לימא קסברי רבנן **שהתורה בלשון קדש נאמרה פירושה שאין שנונה ולמודה בכל לשון פוטרתו מידי הגיית יומם ולילה**

Comment: Can you provide a summary of R' Meir Soloveitchik? Also I don't understand what the Ra'avad is saying. If everyone agrees that the Torah was given in Lashon Ha-kodesh, how is there the question of: "if the Torah was given in every language, one can study it in every language, but if it was not, then it can't"?

Comment: @user6618 ok, done

Comment: @user6618 Everyone agrees that the Torah was written in Lashon ha-Kodesh, but not everyone agrees that the Torah was given/taught exclusively in Lashon ha-Kodesh; the question in the Gemara is whether it was also given/taught in other languages

Comment: See my clarification in my previous comment

Comment: Very nice. I upvoted even though it will only lead to this superseding my answer.